# Alternative for JOIN

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

First Trigger

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Price_Modified]
    ON [dbo].[stock_recieve]
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF UPDATE (Stock_out) 
BEGIN
    UPDATE s
    SET value = new.Item_Price * new.Stock_out
    FROM stock_recieve AS s
    JOIN inserted AS new ON new.[Bill No] = s.[Bill No]
    JOIN deleted AS old ON old.[Bill No] = s.[Bill No]
END;
```

Second Trigger.

```
 ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[newval] 
      ON [dbo].[stock_recieve]
        AFTER UPDATE
    AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF UPDATE (Stock_out) 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE s
        SET Uservalue = new.Item_Price * new.Stock_out
        FROM stock_recieve AS s
        JOIN inserted AS new ON new.[Bill No] = s.[Bill No]
        JOIN deleted AS old ON old.[Bill No] = s.[Bill No]
    END;
```

Result to be obtained on first stock_out update.

```
| Item_Price | Stock_in | Stock_out | Value | Uservalue |
|------------|----------|-----------|-------|-----------|
| 50         | 200      | 100       | 5000  | 5000      |
| 100        | 50       | 20        | 2000  | 2000      |
| 30         | 100      | 40        | 1200  | 1200      |
```

Result to be obtained on second stock_out update.

```
| Item_Price | Stock_in | Stock_out | Value | Uservalue |
|------------|----------|-----------|-------|-----------|
| 50         | 200      | 200       | 10000 | 5000      |
| 100        | 50       | 40        | 4000  | 2000      |
| 30         | 100      | 100       | 3000  | 1800      |
```

The first trigger does what its suppose to do, but I want the second trigger on Uservalue to not add but instead replace the result.
Hope this is clear @Ypercube

Comment: What do you mean with *"updated more than once"*?

Comment: for example, The first time stock_out gets updated (new.Item_Price * new.Stock_out = Uservalue) . 10 * 5 = 50. but if stock_out is updated again on same row 10 * 15 = 200. The Uservalue is suppose to be 150 but it gets added to previous value and becomes 200.

Comment: Is `[Bill No]` the primary key? Show us the `CREATE TABLE` statement and a sample (a few rows before, the `UPDATE` you run and the rows after).

Comment: Yes [Bill No] is the primary key.

Comment: Why are you joining with deleted in your update?

Comment: I also wanted to keep the deleted values if need be, but that line would be irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Please update the question with a sample (as requested above). And if there are more update  triggers in the table, please write that, too. I can't see how it would be possible for a row to end up with having `(Item_Price, Stock_out, Uservalue) = (10, 15, 200)` after an update with this trigger only in place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you want to base the result on `UserValue` on the difference between the new and the old value of `Stock_Out`. Using two triggers for this does not sound like a good idea.

(Using 2 triggers on the same table and action does not sound like a good idea in general, unless the logic is so much complicated that you need to separate it into 2 parts.)

```
-- Drop all existing UPDATE triggers on the table
DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[Price_Modified] ;
DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[newval] ;

-- trigger that updates UserValue based on the diff (new - old) of Stock_Out
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[stockout_modified] 
  ON [dbo].[stock_recieve]
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF UPDATE (Stock_out) 
BEGIN
    UPDATE s
    SET Uservalue = new.Item_Price * (new.Stock_out - old.Stock_out) 
    FROM stock_recieve AS s
    JOIN inserted AS new ON new.[Bill No] = s.[Bill No]
    JOIN deleted AS old ON old.[Bill No] = s.[Bill No]
END;
```

Comment: okay @ypercube, Your logic should work, I did the calculations, just one change, SET Item_Value = new.Value - old.Value     Instead of subtracting stock_out I can subtract old.value from new.value and get the result that I want, but I just cant get the result on Item_Value column with your trigger, I am working on that.

Comment: `Item_Value`? I don't see any such column in the sample you posted

Comment: also changed IF UPDATE (Stock_out) to IF UPDATE (Value). Worked like a charm. Could not have been possible without you @ypercube, all the other contributors and stackoverflow.com. Thank you

Comment: Oh sry its Uservalue not Item_Value. :)

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using a trigger, you should use a Calculated Column.
This way, any change in stock_out would affect the users score.
It would be calculated automaticaly, and without duplicate rows.

An AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER could then be used to store record of previous user score, by reading data from DELETED and inserting it into an audit table.

Comment: But I want the column to be calculated every time stock_out is updated with new value that is added. if stock_out is 100 and updates to 150 I want calculations to be done on 50 and again if it is updated to 300 it should calculate from 150. like 150 * item_price = Uservalue.

Comment: @Raheel Adam Then let Value be a Calculated Column and keep your second trigger to update Uservalue like you do

Comment: Did not originally try this but learned something new Calculated Column, thx for your input.